# cronjob to remove files older than N days with special characters

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create a job to delete files on a linux box older than X days.  Pretty straightforward with:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +X -exec rm {}\;
```

Problem is all my files have special characters b/c they are pictures from a webcam - most contain parenthesis  so the above command fails with "no such file or directory".

Comment: Apart from the missing space between `{}` and `\;`, this should not be failing. Can you copy-paste the exact crontab entry and exact output? Please don't abbreviate error messages or leave out filenames, since they give vital clues as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +X -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Or perhaps:

```
rm $(find /path/to/files -mtime +X);
```

Or even this method using `xargs` instead of `-exec`:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +X | xargs rm -f;
```

Another twist on `xargs` is to use `-print0` which will help the script differentiate between spaces in filenames & spaces between the returned list by using the ASCII `null` character as a file separator:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +X -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f;
```

Or as `man find` explains under `-print0`:

```
This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of
the current file to standard output, followed by an ASCII NUL
character (character code 0).
```

I would also recommend adding the `-maxdepth` and `-type` flags to better control what the script does. So I would use this for a dry-run test:

```
find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1 -exec echo '{}' \;
```

The `-maxdepth` flag controls how many directories down the `find` will execute and `-type` will limit the search to files (aka: `f`) so the script is focused on files only. This will simply `echo` the results. Then when you are comfortable with it, change the `echo` to `rm`.

Comment: The `$(..)` and `xargs` varieties don't work with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Does

`find /path/to/files -mtime +X -print | tr '()' '?' | xargs rm -f`

work?